# Contentful Graphql Location Filter Variables in Swift

Tags: swift, apollo, contentful

My Query is valid in GraphiQL using the Contentful API but when I pass in the same variables and structure using Swift it won't work. How do I pass lat, lon, radius into the query?

Query

```
query MapQuery($circle: Circle) {
  mapCollection(
    where: { location_within_circle: $circle }
  ) {
     items {
      title
      subtitle
      location {
        lat
        lon
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Variables:

```
{
  "circle": {
    "lat" : 11.11,
    "lon": -111.11,
    "radius": 100,
  }
}
```

Swift Code

```
let circle: String = """
                    {
                    "circle": {
                      "lat" : 11.11,
                      "lon": -111.11,
                      "radius": 100,
                    }
                  }
 """

func queryPlaces() async throws -> GraphQLResult<MapQueryQuery.Data>? {
        return await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            Network.shared.apollo.fetch(query: MapQueryQuery(circle: circle)) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let graphQLResult):
                    continuation.resume(returning: graphQLResult)
                case .failure(let error):
                    if let error = error as? Never {
                        continuation.resume(throwing: error)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, `location_within_circle` is an attribute that belongs to the specific Contentful implementation of GraphQL.

You cannot expect to have it available in other implementations.

For example, [8base's implementation](https://www.8base.com/blog/exposing-geojson-and-more-through-a-graphql-api) uses a whole different syntax.